# Serializing List With Attributes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have the following class:

```
public class Group
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

which serializes to:

```
<Group Name="...">
    <Items>
        <Item>
            ...
        </Item>
    </Items>
</Group>
```

I'm trying to avoid the internal list in Group by subclassing it from List:

```
public class Group : List<Item>
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

but the attribute Name is not getting serialized:

```
<Group>
    <Item>
        ...
    </Item>
</Group>
```

Is what I'm trying to do doable?

Comment: I strongly suggest not to inherit from `List<T>`. Instad you should create a class that **has** a member of type `List<T>`. Anyway what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: The last output I got would be great if it had the Name attribute in the Group element.  I'm not so concerned about what the resulting XML looks like, as long as it has all the information I need serialized.  What matters more to me is making the class as intuitive to use as possible.  If the name of the class suggests that it is a list or collection, I would rather not have to reference an internal list inside the class, i.e., a.Find() instead of a.List.Find().

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _I'm trying to avoid the internal list in Group_. The List isn't `internal`, it's `public`. See [Access Modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) for more info.

Comment: I don't mean internal as access modifier.  I mean internal as in List being a property of Group, as opposed to Group itself being a list.